# Baseball pinch hitter question

Tags: baseball

A pinch hitter is up to bat.  A runner on first gets thrown out at second for the third out of the inning.  The pinch hitter is not substituted for the player he was pinch hitting for.  In the next inning who is up to bat the pinch hitter who then completes his bat he did not finish the last inning or the player he was pinch hitting for who had taken the field the inning before?

Comment: Did the pinch hitter step into the batter's box, or was he only on deck?

Comment: @PhilipKendall "A pinch hitter is **up to bat**."

Answer (score 4):

According to rule 5.10(d), "A player once removed from the game may not re-enter that game." The original player is removed from the game as soon as the pinch hitter enters the game. Thus, the original player may not take the field.

Comment: So if the pinch hitter does not take the field after his partial bat still doesn't come back to bat, the player that took the spot in the field is up to bat.

Comment: @Patti : "If such direction to remove the substituted-for player occurs after play has commenced with the substituted-for player in the game, then **the substitute player shall be deemed to have been removed from the game (in addition to the substituted-for player) and shall not enter the game**." So someone else entirely would need to bat.

Comment: The pinch hitter must either take the field or subsequently be replace with another player. The player who was pinch hit for may not take the field.

Answer (score 1):

If there was a pinch hitter on the field, the player he replaced is no longer eligible to go back because he was already substituted and the one who pinched hit for him will replace him on the batting order.